# :hover state element within css multi-column layout on Webkit

Tags: html, css, webkit, multiple-columns

I'm facing a bug with images hovered in a multi-column layout : http://codepen.io/kompuser/pen/CIwFo

On this codepen, I've set a simple :hover property for each img contained in a figure element.

The layout is a multi-columned div set to be horizontally scrolled.

Basically, when not scrolled at all, the hovered img behave the right way.

The bug happens when the container div is (even slightly) scrolled. Then, any img or figure element hovered behaves incorrectly and we can see there is an offset/glitch created.

This is confirmed on Chrome 38 (Windows 7, OS X 10.9), Safari 5.1.7 on Windows, Safari 7.0.6 on OS X.

```
.entry-content{
    display:block;
    -moz-column-width:      240px;
    -webkit-column-width:   240px;
    -ms-column-width:       240px;
    column-width:           240px;

    -moz-column-gap:        1em;
    column-gap:             1em;
    -ms-column-gap:         1em;
    -webkit-column-gap:     1em;

    overflow-y:             hidden;
    overflow-x:             auto;
    height:                 480px;
    font-size:              16px;
    line-height:            19px;
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    clear:both;
    position:relative;
}


.entry-content figure {
  max-width:100%;
}

.entry-content figure:hover img {
  opacity:.5;
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the offset glitch in firefox 33.0 ubuntu

Comment: You're right. As it's  webkit bug only and I forgot to add it to my post.

Comment: Which version/platform? Looks OK in Safari 5.1.7 for Windows...

Comment: @Le-roy It happens on Chrome 38 (Windows 7, Os X 10.9), Safari 7.0.6 (on OS X 10.9)

Comment: Seems OK on Chrome 38.0.2125.101 m Windows 7

Comment: @Le-roy, Actually it also happens on Safari 5.1.7 on Windows 7.You scrolled the horizontal bar and then hovered an img element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's surely a bug, it appears to happen when there is a block with columns and some scrolling. The workaround would be to split those properties to different blocks, so the wrapper would have the scrolling and the inner block would have the columns: http://codepen.io/kizu/pen/saItm

```
.entry-wrapper {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

(of course with removing those styles from the block with columns) and then

```
<div class="entry-wrapper">
  <div class="entry-content">
    …
  </div>
</div>
```

Should be enough to bug not to appear again.